# Add Snowflake ODBC connection in /etc/odbc.ini

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm attempting to set up an ODBC connection on an EC2 server on our companies network. Have been reading Snowflake documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-linux.html).

Following the documentation, I used yum to download and install the driver by adding a file /etc/yum.repos.d/snowflake-odbc.repo and then populating it with:

```
[snowflake-odbc]
name=snowflake-odbc
baseurl=https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/linux/2.22.1/
gpgkey=https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/Snowkey-37C7086698CB005C-gpg
```

I then ran `yum install snowflake-odbc`

This appears to have added a connection to our existing `/etc/odbc.ini` file:

```
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=SF_ACCOUNT.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=SF_ACCOUNT
```

Chancing my luck I tested this connection in it's current format but it doesn't work. Seems I need to locate some more info / name value pairs and I'm unsure where to get them:

Driver= wants a path to a .so file that I thought would have been installed with my steps outlined above. Not sure where to find this file or what path to use?

When I tested the connection the error I received said I was missing a UID.

[The section of the documentation on dns entries](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#odbc-ini-file-dsn-entries) has additional details of which settings can be added to `odbc.ini`, including an example

```
Driver      = /usr/jsmith/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
Description =
server      = yz23456.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
role        = analyst
database    = sales
warehouse   = analysis
```

Does anyone know where can I find out which settings I need to add to get the odbc connection to work?

Comment: Are you just looking to add the UID?  That should be documented as well and you can add it along with any other entries that are required by your test program to the odbc.ini:   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#connection-parameters

Comment: Have you configured also **/etc/odbcinst.ini** file as I don't see it mentioned in your post? I see you added the library path directly to odbc.ini but try as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-linux.html#odbcinst-ini-file-driver-registration)

Comment: Hi @Sergiu I have not configured /etc/odbcinst.ini.... I have not used it on other odbc conns and never properly understood what it's used for.

Comment: In your current odbc,ini add one extra row with **uid=<user>** that is used for login in Snowflake and an extra row with **tracing=6** to have logging. Once you try to connect log files starting with **snowflake_** will be created in **/tmp**. They should give us a better idea why you can't connect.